# SQL Server 2000 strange subquery problem

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2000, subquery

There's a strange behaviour that is drive me crazy.

I've a table of users and a table of permissions in an old SQL Server 2000 database.
This database is a mess, many tables have no PK and there are no relations between the tables... but I couldn't fix it (and honestly I don't think this is related to the problem I have).

```
Users:
IDRecord -> PK money
-- other fields

Permissions:
IDRecord -> money (is not a PK)
IDUser   -> money (refers to Users.IDRecord WITHOUT FK)
Function -> varchar
-- other fields
```

I want to get the User's ids of the users without any permission.

My first approach was to write something as:

```
select distinct IDRecord 
from Users
where IDRecord not in (
    select IDUser from Permissions
)
```

That returns me no rows.

But I KNOW there are users without permissions, so I write a second query:

```
select distinct U.IDRecord 
from Users U
left join Permissions P
    on P.IDUser = U.IDRecord
where P.IDRecord is null
```

that correctly returns the users without permissions.

So, where's the problem?

Why the first doesn't work?

Comment: Turns out that NOT IN never returns TRUE if the list (whether manual or a subquery) contains at least one NULL. Seems like it's by design.

Comment: So, as an alternative to Adam's solution, you could modify the subquery as follows: `select IDUser from Permissions where IDUser is not null`. Or maybe it's time to review your schema and prohibit the NULLs in that column at all.

Comment: You're right, specifically on review the database schemas. But this is an old DB I found when started to work here, there are many applications running on it, any structural modify will surely compromise something... If my boss say "no" I'm unable to fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behavior.
It is expected because SQL has [three-valued logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29).
In other words: for those users who have no permissions, there is no result (NULL) returned by your subquery.
Your `WHERE` condition is not satisfied in those cases because a value can never equal nor not equal NULL.

Alternatives:
1) use a `LEFT JOIN` (as you have done), or
2) use `NOT EXISTS`, e.g.:

```
SELECT DISTINCT IDRecord 
  FROM Users u
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 1 
           FROM Permissions p 
          WHERE p.IDUser = u.IDRecord
       );
```

---

Edit: More detail on how 3VL can bite you if you're not careful:
A possibly counter-intuitive result occurs if you do something like this...

```
...
WHERE a_column <> 'some value';
```

Suddenly rows where `a_column` is NULL disappear from your results.
To get them back you can do this:

```
...
WHERE (a_column <> 'some value' OR a_column IS NULL);
```

Comment: Great! It works as you said. But can you be more specific? I've not understand WHY my "not in" version failed. So, where is supposed to use a "not in" clause? Many thanks!

Comment: I added another 3VL-related example. WRT `NOT IN`, I never use it :D

Comment: OMG, I've used 'NOT IN' so many times... maybe this problem is related to sql server 2000 only, or even to 2005 and 2008?

Comment: This behavior is ANSI-compliant AFAIK. Every SQL dialect I've used has it.

Comment: I don't understand that either. I mean, the `select IDUser from Permissions` subquery is not correlated, it's constant for every IDRecord value being checked, just as if you manually typed in all the values returned, in the form of `(12, 23, 789...)`. How the entire query could result in no rows is absolutely beyond me. :\

Comment: Yes, and is this that made me crazy. I've used this synthax billion times with no problem. But in this specific case it simply doesn't work, but the @Adam version works

Comment: @Adam: Seems like it's just the other way. If you *do* include NULL, then you get *no* result. My conclusion then is that the subquery in the OP's script returns NULLs among other things.

Comment: @Andriy: yes, your conclusion is correct! (Deleted earlier comment.)

Comment: @Adam: the subquery returned NULLs in fact! So there was the problem. Many thanks guys!